# Use of Filter contacts in the data extension entry source with Jouney builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

What is the use of `Filter contacts` in the Journey builder under the entry source as data extension.

[image]

I have a different fields in the data extension and if i filter using the different field in another data extension, how it going to identify the exact record in the DE?
Also, what is the main use of this Filter contacts?

Answer (score 1):

> In entry sources, decision split activities, and other Journey Builder
> components, marketers can create a filter to admit contacts based on
> attribute values. Contacts that meet filter conditions are admitted.
> Filters consist of an expression, an attribute, an operator like
> equals or begins with, and a default or restricted value you choose.
> Create multiple expressions, and tell Journey Builder how they work
> together. Alternately, a filter can include attribute-to-attribute
> comparison. Compare contact and journey data attributes as needed.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_create_a_filter.htm&type=5